# Java Applet issue with mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, applet

I have made a .jar file called test.jar and am trying to put it onto a webpage called login.html (all locally). Within the applet tag I have put mysqlconnector.jar and test.jar in the archive section.

When I try to run the applet using: appletviewer "file:///c:/test/login.html" the applet loads but when I try to login and click ok I get the following error

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
    :286)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at staffDatabase.queryStaffID(staffDatabase.java:76)
    at searchStaff.readFromLogin(searchStaff.java:14)
    at loginFrame$1.actionPerformed(loginFrame.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:19
    95)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
    a:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
    .java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242
)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
istener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574
)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.Proper
tyPermission file.encoding read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:12
85)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:650)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:70)
    ... 30 more
```

I've looked at several other websites that suggest the

```
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.Proper
tyPermission file.encoding read)
```

is due to lacking read permissions from policytool, but I have already put all permissions on and this has made no difference.

Any help would be appreciated! I have looked everywhere with no luck so far, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changing your policy file is not going to cut it, you still need to [sign the applet](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html). Note that ss an alternative you may choose to deploy your app via [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html). This will get you a higher default set of permissions, but for what you are doing (requesting socket permissions) the application will still need to be signed.

Comment: The security sand-box used for applets and JWS apps. is the same, with only slight differences in the policies used.  Examples of differences are 1) even a signed applet cannot call `System.exit(n)` 2) JWS apps. have not only `all-permissions` and  sand-boxed, but also another level in between.  Otherwise, +1.  Avoid policy files, they are only good for arcane situations (like development, though I sign Jars in the build, if need be).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - JNLP indeed doesn't give enough permissions for the OP to be able to connect to a database without signing. I'll update my answer.